# Nautilus not showing folder icons in home folder

Tags: nautilus, icons

Usually folders like pictures and documents show up with an icon in nautilus. Since I have a 1TB hard drive for storage I decided to put the folders there instead and create a symbolic link to my home folder. At first the folders had icons just like before, but not anymore. How do I bring these icons back?

Edit: Here is a screenshot of what I mean. I am sorry it's in swedish. For example the folder "Bilder" which means "Pictures" in my home folder usually has a default icon which is now gone. [image: What the folders look like]

Comment: I eventually  solved it by manually selecting icons from `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/64`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is checking your view settings, and checking your preference for display. The main options are List and Icons, maybe 1 or 2 others. Open Nautilus to the folder in question, and try those.

Beyond that, to configure a custom icon, you could create a [Desktop Entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) file. These are the files Ubuntu uses internally to create visible shortcuts and app launchers. You can make one from scratch, or copy and modify from /usr/share/applications.

Does that help?

Comment: I added a screenshot to clarify what I mean.